# How can I run a makefile that contains an awk script on windows?

Tags: windows, awk, makefile

I have an .awk script which is used to assign names and numbers to the conditions and trials in a .tsv file for one subject.

I then have a makefile where the awk is implemented combining many .tsv files for many subjects.

The output is a single file containing all subject data (with condition names and trial numbers) for later use in an R analysis. I have no idea how to execute the Makefile/awk implementation on windows though, as these files were initially created and run on a mac by a collaborator.

I've searched around, but the information I've encountered has been a little beyond my knowledge-base.

Comment: It may be an idea to post the `Makefile` and the `awk` files... in the mean time, there is an `awk` port for Windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `make` and `awk`, the syntax should be identical to other platforms.

```
output.tsv:
    awk -f scriptname.awk input1.tsv input2.tsv >$@
```

A generalized rule with dependencies declared:

```
output.tsv: input1.tsv input2.tsv
    awk -f scriptname.awk $^ >$@
```

Sometimes you even want to depend on changes in the script file, too:

```
output.tsv: scriptname.awk input1.tsv input2.tsv
    # Tricky: make sure the script name is the first dependency!
    awk -f $^ >$@
```

Of course, if the script's output contains file names, they will probably be in Unix format; but Windows should generally be able to cope with forward slash instead of backslash as directory separator.  There are probably other idiosyncrasies of Windows you will need to cope with, too.

> If you chose Windows in the first place, we assume you like it that way.